# Error while executing transactions in hyperledger fabric

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, peer

I'm executing chaincode transactions on **hyperledger fabric** but I'm getting some weird error as follows:

```
2019-07-01T07:21:40.006Z - warn: [Transaction]: _validatePeerResponses: Received error response from peer: message=2 UNKNOWN: Transaction is not valid. Got [d9be41c821926332edc7107655fa4e7c31d34cc5cfbcb4bbc54c658b254c6c1e], expected [239121c61652599982cb82e3a25065d04187d73391c17bb26d9584c7e8b6dee8], stack=Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Transaction is not valid. Got [d9be41c821926332edc7107655fa4e7c31d34cc5cfbcb4bbc54c658b254c6c1e], expected [239121c61652599982cb82e3a25065d04187d73391c17bb26d9584c7e8b6dee8]
1|server  |     at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/ubuntu/rest/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
1|server  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28)
1|server  |     at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
1|server  |     at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/ubuntu/rest/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
1|server  |     at callback (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24), code=2, , details=Transaction is not valid. Got [d9be41c821926332edc7107655fa4e7c31d34cc5cfbcb4bbc54c658b254c6c1e], expected [239121c61652599982cb82e3a25065d04187d73391c17bb26d9584c7e8b6dee8]
1|server  | Error: Failed to submit transaction: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
1|server  |     at invoke_transaction (/home/ubuntu/app/express-api-app-v2.js:310:15)
```

Sometimes transactions get processed but sometimes it gives me this error

Answer (score -1):

error is name is undefined  at

> /home/ubuntu/app/express-api-app-v2.js line number 310

as the feild you are trying to send is undefined the chaincode throws error.

do comment if you face issues.

Comment: Its not a problem with an undefined parameter that line just prints the error. There is some transaction validation problem of in our hyperledger fabric network setup as sometimes the transaction is successful but sometimes not.

Comment: whats the key used in the putsate?

Comment: Can u please let me know why chaincode is accessible in some cases while sometime not? Because while the above error occurs there is no output in my chaincode container logs.

Comment: I faced the same issue twice once when i was working on fabric 1.1,That i resolved by updating docker to a newer version...and again sometime earlier when the key sent to the chaincode was undefined.

Comment: I'm also facing the same error , sometimes transaction is confirmed and sometimes it throws error.

Comment: It's because your peer is not able to get a valid txid against the transaction